# Is there a standard convention for type names in xml schemas?

Tags: xml, xsd, naming-conventions, naming

Is there a standard naming convention for xml schema (xsd)?
In particular, how do i name types?
Variants:
`<xs:complexType name="typeName></xs:complexType>`
or
`<xs:complexType name="TypeName></xs:complexType>`
or
`<xs:complexType name="TTypeName></xs:complexType>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

The XSD spec doesn't say anything about this (of course).
Also, if you look at various XML schemas found on http://www.w3.org, they use any kind of names as they please.

Typically, it is compound names, where each part conveys some additional meaning
and starts from an upper case letter, e.g.:

```
xs:simpleRestrictionType
```

Sometimes, they separate parts of the name with hyphens (at that, hold all letters lowercase), e.g.:

```
xsl:element-only-versioned-element-type
```

or use dots instead of hyphens:

```
xhtml.area.events.attlist
```

Sometimes, when upper-case letters are used to highlight name parts, 
the names of XSD types are preferred to start with an upper-case letter, 
whereas names of elements and attributes from lower-case letter.
But again, this is not any kind of strict rule (for instance, XML schema for XML schemas has both:
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd).

I think, you simply need to stick to one of theses styles throughout all your XML schema(s)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no standard convention in the XSD user community as a whole.

How should you name types?  In any way (subject to the limitations on XML names) that you and those who read your schema documents find clear and helpful.